# Set background-image css to the featured image in wordpress using jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

for reference
http://vvcap.net/db/Bs03ucQSrylV5LBiWduY.htp here's a thumbnail of featured image of a post
http://vvcap.net/db/_45qWkuQwluTrYF51tFn.htp here's a square i want to set the background-image of.  The small square is made from a post loop (shown below).  Inside the loop is a a check to see if the post as a "featured image attracted"

**CSS:** currently this is the only css that styles the div bg. (this should be replaced)

```
 section > div { background:#00c8e8;}
```

**Compiled source HTML** the second section posts a featured image(ontop of div) as example. First section has no featured image.

```
<section  class="resource">
   <div> 
        <a href="http://localhost/dov1/?custom_type=logo-design" rel="bookmark" title=" Logo Design">Logo Design</a>
  </div>
</section>

<section  class="resource">
  <div> 
        <a href="http://localhost/dov1/?custom_type=test" rel="bookmark" title=" Magazine Spread">Magazine Spread</a>

            <img width="125" height="125" src="http://localhost/dov1/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/project2_web-125x125.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="project2_web" title="project2_web" />     
 </div>
</section>
```

**HTML/PHP**

```
<?php 

        $args = array(  
        'post_type' => 'custom_type', 
        'posts_per_page' => '-1' 
        );

        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <section  class="resource">
              <div> 
          <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title=" <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
                <?php 
            // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it. 
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) 
            { 
          //run jQuery here (prob replace the_post_thumbnail();)
              the_post_thumbnail();
        } 
        ?>
    </a> </div>
</section>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I'm not very strong with jQuery or php. Luckily, the logic to this process makes sense.

1. Loop the posts (check)
2. Test to see if posts have featured image (check)
3. Execute jQuery to replace the background images with the_post_thumbnail();
4. Profit!

Where we run into another caveat is how do we distinguish and assign the distinguished the proper background image?  I only have 1 form fitting css style.  It would make sense if it treated the process per entry.  Unfortunately, wouldn't it rewrite over each entry?  I know this is a big question stack but please I'll love you forever for the help!

Matthew

**UPDATED HTML SOURCE**

```
   <section  class="resource">

      <div> 

            <a href="http://localhost/dov1/?custom_type=test" rel="bookmark" title=" Magazine Spread">Magazine Spread</a>

            <img width="125" height="125" src="http://localhost/dov1/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/project2_web-125x125.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="project2_web" title="project2_web" />      </div>

    </section>
```

Comment: To use jQuery we need to see the (relevant) rendered HTML ('view source').

Comment: sorry it is there.  under compiled source

Comment: I can post all the source if you like?  I'll update the whole page of source if you would like but thats what is made from the posts

Comment: I did remove the_post_thumbnail(); from the source i'll add it in comments here sorry if this lead to any confusion.

Comment: Great. And which of those divs in that 'compiled source' has the background-image you want to use as the background for which other div?

Comment: it will be each set of divs.  there will be many posts.  each post will have a featured image.  i want the loop to grab the featured image and replace the section > div {background-image:_____) with the post's featured image.

Comment: I updated the code above also.

Comment: The featured image being the only `img` element that's in the `div`? And the image should become the background-image of the `div` itself? Should the `img` be removed subsequently?

Comment: Yes sir david thomas you got it.  the image should become the background image of the div itself!  Also you're correct the img overlayed image should be removed subsequently!  Ahh, you're getting me excited, DO YOU KNOW HOW TO DO THIS!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there's only one `img` element per `section` element, and that you wish *that* image to become the `background-image` of the parent `div` of the `img`:

```
$('section img').each(
    function(){
        var src = this.src,
            h = $(this).height(),
            w = $(this).width();
        $(this).closest('div').css({
            'min-width' : w,
            'min-height' : h,
            'background-image' : 'url(' + src + ')',
            'background-repeat' : 'no-repeat',
            'background-position' : '50% 50%'
        });
    }).remove();​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/GK2pd/).

References:

- [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).
- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/).
- [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).
- [`width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/).

Comment: it works! however, the .remove accually removes both of them.  I tested this by taking away .remove();  and it showed both.  Unfortunatly when i removed    the_post_thumbnail(); it took away both.  Any idea on how to get ride of the overlay image but keep the background image?

Comment: "The `.remove()` accually removes both of them..." both of *what*? Using Chromium 17, Firefox 11 and Opera 11.61 (all on Ubuntu 11.04) don't reproduce the problem you *seem* to be describing. In those browsers you get the background image and remove the `img` elements. What're you expecting/wanting to happen?

Comment: It is the PHP that is creating the problem the_post_thumbnail(); Your code is great!  just getting 2 images over another

Comment: I will repost source above to show you what the php is doing. so we can maybe write another line to remove it.

Comment: What was the problem that you solved? And how? It might be worth posting as an actual answer, in order that this post might help future users of this site.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) you can just pass that information as the second parameter.

**CSS**

```
.post-thumbnail {
    background:#00c8e8;
}
```

**PHP**

```
$size = array( 32, 32 );
$attr = array( 'class' => 'post-thumbnail' );
the_post_thumbnail( $size, $attr );
```

---

In order to make the post thumbnail a background I would use get_the_post_thumbnail()

```
<?php $bg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id, $size, $attr)); ?>
<div style="background: <?php echo $bg; ?>;">...</div>
```

You would have to pass the parameters you want to it - specific post ids or whatever.

Comment: I believe there was some confusion in the code I linked you.. right now the the_post_thumbnail(); sits on the top of the box http://vvcap.net/db/E8hsVqoS-XW-yilykDId.htp heres a better picture.  I tried the code but it seems to not work.  perhaps I'm just placing it incorrectly?

Comment: So are you saying instead of an image tag you want it to be a div bg?

Comment: yes yes!  After most analyzy I've figure that this will be quite a process.  I must loop all the posts then use jquery to replace css per post?  This method makes sense but seems really difficult.  Would you understand how to accomplish this process?